# DataGridView tipo de columna C#

Tags: c#, datagrid, type

Tengo un DataGrid con una columna tipo DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, pero quiero pasarlo a tipo de columna DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, entonces hago lo siguiente

```
if (miDataTable.Rows.Count > 0);
                {
                    // elimina la columna de un data grid
                    dgvCitas.Columns.Remove("pCita");

                    // crea una columna 
                    var column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    column.Name = "pCita";
                    column.HeaderText = "Cita #1";

                    //agrega una columna al data grid
                    dgvCitas.Columns.Insert(2, column);

                }
```

El problema es que ese código está dentro de un ciclo y cada vez me borra la columna y me crea una nueva borrando de igual forma los datos que pueda tener, por eso ocupo que me ayuden a hacer algo parecido a esto **(Cabe mencionar que el siguiente código no funciona, error de sintaxis)**.

```
if (miDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 && dgvCitas.Columns[numCita].ValueType.ToString()="DataGridViewComboBoxColumn") ;
                {
\\ mi codigo
}
```

Es decir, ocupo que me ayuden a comparar el tipo de columna que es,   porque si es de tipo texbox no debería ingresar al if

Answer (score 0):

Esto responde a mi pregunta, Espero a alguien le sea útil.

Eso compara si una columna del datagrid es de tipo ComboBox.

```
if (dgvCitas.Columns[numCita].GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn")
    {
        \\ nuestro codigo
    }
```

Comment: Y no es más fácil (y corto) esto? if (dgvCitas.Columns[numCita] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) {}